# « Le temps a passé » vs « Le temps est passé »

Tags: sens, auxiliaires

Quel est l'auxiliaire correct?

S'ils sont tous les deux possibles, quelle est la différence de sens?

- Le temps a passé
- Le temps est passé

Comment: Le [Wiktionnaire explique la distinction en passant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passer#Note). Une réponse détaillant davantage et fournissant quelques exemples serait bienvenue.

Comment: Je vous la distinction dans "on a passé de la drogue, quand on est passé à Bogota". On ne pourrait donc pas écrire "le temps a passé"? (pourtant, ça sonne bien à mes oreilles).

Comment: Au Canada, on utilise couramment les deux auxiliaires, *avoir* et *être*, quand le verbe est intransitif, et seulement *avoir* quand il est transitif. Je ne suis pas certain si la distinction de sens correspond précisément à celle qui est préconisée dans les dictionnaires, à laquelle Chop fait référence ci-dessous. Je dirais que « Le temps a passé » sonne beaucoup mieux que « Le temps est passé ».

Comment: @Keith D'accord avec ton analyse mais aussi avec ton appréciation finale (je vis en France, je le précise pour élargir la portée géographique de ta remarque).

Comment: @RomainVALERI Comme quoi cela peut être très subjectif ou régional. France métropolitaine également, mais je préfère largement l'utilisation de l'auxiliaire être.

Comment: @rds Je sais que c'est seulement un exemple, mais c'est franchement irrespectueux, spécialement pour les Colombiens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La question se pose et les deux sens sont valables. L'Académie dans son Dictionnaire cite la règle et l'exemple suivant :

> On considère traditionnellement que, lorsqu'il est conjugué avec l'auxiliaire Avoir, le verbe Passer exprime l'action, et que, avec l'auxiliaire Être, il exprime son résultat : l'hiver a passé bien vite, l'hiver est maintenant passé. Cependant, l'usage actuel tend à faire prévaloir l'auxiliaire Être dans les deux cas.

**Les deux tournures sont donc valides.** Comme impliqué par la question, il y a une nuance entre les deux. Pour reprendre les exemples de [cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/cl-r) :

- « Sous mes yeux, le temps a passé sur ce paysage sans laisser de traces » (je suis témoin de l'action).
- « Le temps est passé, rien n'a changé ici durant mon voyage » (je suis témoin du résultat).

L'usage avec l'auxiliaire « avoir » sans autre complément me laisse un sentiment d'incomplétude. Si l'on décrit la façon dont il est passé (« Le temps a passé vite »), ce sentiment disparaît. Il est devenu courant d'utiliser « être » dans tous les cas, mais la nuance existe.

Ceci semble difficile à appliquer à tous les exemples. Il est théoriquement possible de dire « Le camion a passé » mais sans que je puisse le justifier, cette phrase ne me satisfait pas.

---

<sub>Sources :</sub>

- <sub>http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic32501-le-temps-est-passe-ou-le-temps-a-passe.html</sub>
- <sub>https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passer#Note</sub>

Comment: Et paff 1k ! :D Sinon, `Votre temps est révolu.` sonne correctement, alors pourquoi *"passé"* ne conviendrait-il pas?

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit que « Le temps est passé » n'était pas valide, mais je comprends le manque de clarté. Je vais éditer ma réponse de ce pas.

Comment: @Chop J'ai effacé mes commentaires pour ne pas embrouiller la réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Pour compléter les réponses déjà proposées :

Selon que l'on considère le temps comme :

> *durée mesurée scientifiquement*, donc comme un objet quantifiable, le verbe *avoir* est préférable, car les objets sont multiples et sont par nature inertes, on peut les posséder ou les maîtriser.

... ou comme :

> *époque, ère,* voire *déité*, le verbe *être* semble convenir, car le temps représente une unité, cette dernière existe en soit comme la période gallo-romaine, et Chronos a existé dans l'imaginaire Grec ; deux représentations singulières du temps.

---

En remplaçant *temps* par *secondes*, il y a une approche où *trente secondes* (et donc le *temps*)...

... représente une durée que l'on a perçu seconde après seconde :

> - Trente secondes ont passé et la porte s'est ouverte.

... représentent une période singulière, sont une limite :

> - Les trente secondes sont passées, l'épreuve est finie.

<sup>*Ce sont là des nuances intuitives où l'emploi de l'auxiliaire est induit par les usages en cours, aucune faute n'est à craindre si l'on inverse les auxiliaires .*</sup>